# What does width null signify in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I was going through few questions on SO and few apps where I came across the following style configuration:-

```
  container: {
    flex:1,
    width: null,
  },
```

I was wondering what is the use of `width:null` here. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<Image source={require('./images/MacWallPaper.jpg')} style={styles.container}>

</Image>
```

*When you don't specify `width: null` and `height: null` component fetches actual width and height of the source image.*

```
container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
}
```

*when you explicitly specify `width: null` and `height: null` component won't make use of actual width and height of the image.*

```
container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
   // remove width and height to override fixed static size
   width: null,
   height: null,
}
```

***Watch [this](http://reactcafe.com/how-to-set-a-full-screen-background-image-in-react-native/) video***

Comment: In typescript, its type is undefined or number, how can we do this in TS?